# Android setOnItemClickListener inside adapter not crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I made an Image gallery using a GridView. It is done but now I'm trying to add some interaction with a "setOnItemClickListener" inside a getView function of an adapter. Here is the code of my adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    //Basic standard adapter functions

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        GridView mygrid = (GridView) imageView.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        mygrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int position, long l) {
                //Do something
            }
        });
```

That code compiles for me, but when I do the OnClick to load this view, it crashes. If I comment the setOnItemClickListener call, everything works for me so I guess there is my error.

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can we have the stacktrace?

Comment: out of all the questions, why do you need the Listener into the adapter?

Answer (score 2):

`GridView mygrid = (GridView) imageView.findViewById(R.id.gallery);`

mygrid is probably null. It is really bad idea to call `setOnItemClickListener` inside of the `getView` method you should call it either in construstor or outside of the adapter.